# Hiding git commits in release branch

Tags: git

I have a git project with a number of commits.

a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i

I would like to push this to a release branch where only tagged commits can be seen. e.g.

a-d-h

I have tried with rebase and squash merge, but nothing seems to work. 
I read that rebase is not possible once the commits have been pushed to a git server, can this be my problem.
Anybody have a good hint please?

Edit

I found a bit ugly but useable solution.
I created a release repository, and a small script to check out the release commit and copy it to the release repository and commit it there.

And thanks for the replies saying that it actually was impossible.

Comment: You can't "hide" commits, you either have them in your repository, or you don't. Squashing them using either merge or rebase will remove them, folding their changes into another commit. Is that what you want? You will lose the original commits unless you keep a copy of them somewhere "out of sight".

Comment: You may want to edit this post and clarify what you mean by "seen" and "hide". If you just want to take the same series of changes and squash them down into 3 commits, that is one thing, if you are expecting to somehow have the changes in the files, but the commits are no longer in the log, but the commits still exist - that is quite different and not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you would like to see is a straight branch with only a few revisions you would like to publish and that there is *no* relation to the history of the branches that you use for development, you could do so in 2 ways:

- by using commit-tree. With `git commit-tree` you could create revision specifying the parent (or parents) and the tree (the content of the files on that revision). 
  You could specify the tree from any revision that you like and you could provide the parent you would like your new revision to have. That way you "skip" all branch history, if that's what you want. Not beautiful, but possible. If you wanted to create revision M using the **tree of revision G** having A as parent:

  - Get the tree object for revision G (git cat-file -p G)
  - Create revision object: git commit-tree -p A -m "Here's the comment for the revision" tree-object-for-G-from-git-cat-file
  - Point a branch to this new revision
  - Voila
- By checking out the tree you would like and committing. So, say you checkout on revision A:

  - git checkout A
  - git checkout G -- . # checkout the whole content of the project on revision G... not sure if files will be deleted/renamed... careful
  - git commit -m "Comment for revision"
  - Create a new branch on this revision and you are done.